# Name each variable differently in a loop

Tags: matlab, variables, for-loop

I have created a .dat file of file names. I want to read into MATLAB each file in that list and give the data a different name. Currently, each iteration just overwrites the last one.

I found that a lot of people give this answer:

```
for i=1:10
  A{i} = 1:i;
end
```

However, it isn't working for my problem. Here's what I am doing

```
flist = fopen('fnames.dat'); % Open the list of file names

nt = 0; % Counter will go up one for each file loaded
while ~feof(flist) % While end of file has not been reached
    for i = 1:6 % Number of filenames in the .dat file

    % For each file
    fname = fgetl(flist); % Reads next line of list, which is the name of the next data file
    disp(fname); % Stores name as string in fname

    nt = nt+1; % Time index

    % Save data

    data{i} = read_mixed_csv(fname, '\t'); % Reads in the CSV file% Open file
    data{i} = data(2:end,:); % Replace header row

    end
end
```

The code runs with no errors, but only one `data` variable is saved.

My fnames.dat contains this:
IA_2007_MDA8_O3.csv
IN_2007_MDA8_O3.csv
MI_2007_MDA8_O3.csv
MN_2007_MDA8_O3.csv
OH_2007_MDA8_O3.csv
WI_2007_MDA8_O3.csv

If possible, I would really like to name `data` something more intuitive. Like `IA` for the first file, `IN` for the second and so on. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why not write separate statements, one for each file? Since you have six files, you need six lines in your script. In such a case there's no point in using a `for` loop.

Comment: The thing is that I will eventually have 50 files. Rewriting for each would not be reasonable.

Comment: Hm, and you really want to have 50 different variables in your workspace, instead of one cell array with 50 elements? If you're sure you want this, have a look at `eval`.

Comment: I tried to use eval, but didn't know how to set it up. As for using one cell array, I tried that, but I couldn't because each variable is a different length.

Comment: In a cell array, there is no limitation on the size or type of the elements. Sorry, have to go now. I'll check back tomorrow and see whether your question is still open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the loop is the problem:

```
data{i} = data(2:end,:);
```

I don't know what exactly happens I did not run your code, but `data(2:end,:)` refers to the second to last dataset, not the second to last line.

Try:

```
thisdata = read_mixed_csv(fname, '\t');
data{i} = thisdata(2:end,:);
```

Comment: Can you think of a way I can do this and have them come out as separate variables? Maybe even name them different things as I mentioned in my question?

Comment: @shizishan The whole point of using something like `data{i}` is **not to have separate variables**. This way, all your data is stored in one variable, which you can index easily. Using separate variables is not efficient and not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of what data came from which file, save out a second cell array with the names:

```
thisdata = read_mixed_csv(fname, '\t');
data{i} = thisdata(2:end,:);
names{i} = fname(1:2); % presuming you only need first two letters.
```

If you need a specific part of the filename that's not always the same length look into `strtok` or `fileparts`. Then you can use things like `strcmp` to check the cell array `names` for where the data labelled `IA` or whichever is stored.

Comment: Thanks. This at least gives me a variable with the names in order for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Daniel the simple way to store data of various sizes in a cell array.

data{1} = thisdata(2:end,:)

However, if the names are really important, you could consider using a struct instead. For example:

```
dataStruct(1).numbers= thisdata(2:end,:);
dataStruct(1).name= theRelevantName
```

Of course you could also just add them to the cell array:

```
dataCell{1,1} = thisdata(2:end,:);
dataCell{1,2} = theRelevantName
```